# If url is the homepage (/ or index.php) do this

Tags: php

I'm trying to hide some content on my homepage using this code:

```
<?php   

  $homeurl = 'index.php';                               
  $homepage = "/";
  $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  if($currentpage == $homepage or $currentpage == 'index.php') {
  echo 'no content';
  } else {
    echo 'content';
  }                                     

?>
```

It works if the url is simply www.mysite.com but not if the url is www.mysite.com/index.php - I need the content hidden in both instances.
My PHP is very basic so please forgive me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you need add `/` before `index.php` too:

```
$homeurl = '/index.php';
```

Your solution of detecting index looks a bit weird, but there is not enough code (for example frontend) to help with.

Comment: Thank you! so simple... works just as I need it to now!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the PHP magic constant and basename()

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php
- https://www.php.net/basename

Here is the logic;

```
if( basename(__FILE__) == "index.php" ) {
  //Hide content
} else {
  //Show content
}
```

For example;

```
http://localhost/test/
index.php

http://localhost/test/index.php
index.php
```

Comment: Imagine if he's doing rewrite, and any request will go to `index.php` so your code will always executes for `hide content`

Comment: The OP didn't specify that they were using `index.php` as a router.

Comment: So why does he use `else` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to keep old SO pages afloat, so excuse my late reply :)
I think a better solution to detect if we're on the homepage is something like this:

```
function isHomepage() {
  $page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
  return $page === 'index.php';
}
```

The above code would work whether placed in the homepage file itself or in some included page (unlike `__FILE__`) and it would also work if the URL of the page doesn't explicitly have `index.php` in it, for example `http://example.com/app/` would still work correctly.

However, if you're using routing and `index.php` is the entry page for your controllers, the above would always return `true`. In that case you should parse `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead.