# How to check if url is the homepage

Tags: php, request-uri

Found this answer [If url is the homepage (/ or index.php) do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664906/if-url-is-the-homepage-or-index-php-do-this) which was really helpful however doesn't fully answer my question.

I have an index of site for school that shows all my folders to different assignments. so my homepage is actually domain/folder/index.html

so when I ask if $currentpage == /midterm/index.php || /midterm/ it always triggers as true even if I am on /midterm/add.php

```
<?php
$homeurl = '/midterm/index.php';
$homepage = '/midterm';
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($currentpage == $homeurl || $homepage) {
    echo '<div class="hero"></div>';
}
```

Comment: It will you have no condition set for `$homepage`.

Comment: ^ `$homepage` as a defined var is going to return true in this case

Comment: ^ true that....

Comment: Oh how stupid of me haha I was to worried about the REQUEST_URI that I overlooked the simple answer. Thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you should put in an answer so I can accept it as you gave it to me first. If not I will close the question with one of the below answers.

Comment: The guys below deserve it, they made the effort in answering ;p

Comment: if your comparing 1 string to many others `in_array()` id handy, but for 2 i wouldent worry `if (in_array($currentpage, array($homeurl,$homepage))){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your conditional: `if ($currentpage == $homeurl || $homepage)` will always return `true` because you are stating that `$currentpage` must equal `$homeurl`, **OR** just simply `$homepage`. Adding brackets helps showcase this:

```
if ( ($currentpage == $homeurl) || ($homepage) )
```

Because `$homepage` is set, it's **[`truthy`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)**, and evaluates to `true`. Because only **one part** of the conditional needs to be `true` due to your `OR` (`||`), the condition returns `true` as a whole.

To resolve this, you're looking to check whether `$currentpage` is equal to `$homeurl` **OR** `$currentpage` is equal to `$homepage`:

```
if ($currentpage == $homeurl || $currentpage == $homepage)
```

Which, with added brackets, evaluates to:

```
if ( ($currentpage == $homeurl ) || ($currentpage == $homepage) )
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your if statement is checking to see if `$homepage` is set, not if `$homepage` is equal to `$currentpage`.

```
if ($currentpage == $homeurl || $currentpage == $homepage) {
    echo '<div class="hero"></div>';
}
```